# Where do people leaving academia go?

Tags: career-path, reference-request

Is there any extensive research/study/survey that looked at where people that leave academia go?

I mostly interested in the computer science field (machine learning) in the US, but curious about other fields and locations as well.

People leaving academia can be PhD students or after (tenure-track, tenured, soft-money research positions, national lab researchers, etc.).

Comment: Big Rock Candy Mountain?

Comment: @NateEldredge or is it the Lake of Fire?

Answer (score 2):

Copied from [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/30606/what-are-the-main-reasons-why-academics-leave-academia) per Franck's request: the NIH recently examined where people with a biomedical Ph.D. ended up. The results of their survey are discussed [here](http://nexus.od.nih.gov/all/2012/06/22/so-what-does-the-biomedical-research-workforce-look-like/).